# C# Comparing buttons's images

Tags: c#

so I'm just making a simple tic tac toe with 9 buttons. I am giving 1 image (circle or X) to any button pressed as background. When the program starts all buttons don't have any background or text.
So I created a check() method that returns true if someone won.
I only coded the top row to check if it's working, and it doesn't...

[image: the code]

Any tips could help :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx just because they might be the same picture, doesn't mean they're the same image. I wouldn't use a comparison of the image to do what you're doing, I would store the state of the box you checked (x, o or empty) and compare the state of the cells that way.

Comment: FYI, it's best to include code as text rather than images.  There's built-in syntax coloring provided your code is all indented at least 4 spaces.  (And there's a "code" button to click in the editor that will do the indenting for you.)

Comment: @adv12 Thanks I will follow that way in my future questions and answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for the best if you keep the original grid inside a multidimentional array or list, and then update the images according to that list.

```
List<List<bool>> grid = new List<List<bool>>();
bool isx = grid[x][y];
```

Or you can also work by setting the 'Tag' attribute.

```
Button1.Tag = "x";

// Reading the tag as follows:
string result = (string)Button1.Tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it guys.**
I just created 9 static booleans and everytime a button was pressed, its boolean changed value. (true for X false for circle). Then in the check method I just checked the value of the boolean. Thanks to Hammerstein for the idea.

Comment: How do you keep track of which spaces haven't been clicked at all?  Sounds like you need a data type with three possible values, maybe a nullable bool (bool?)  (Or for example an Enum with values X, O, and None)

Comment: @adv12 I just check in the check() method if (!button1.Enabled && !button2.Enabled && !button3.Enabled) if true I check if (b1 == b2 && b2 == b3) then etc etc
Note: when a players pressed a button. it goes button.enabled = fasle;